# Magento 2: move shipping method list to new custom step

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, magento2.2.3

I have created custom step to checkout page between shipping and payment step

[image]

I want to move shipping method step to my custom step

[image]

how can I move this to new custom step. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you move shipping method to new step ? i am also searching for this.